# Align divs vertically but keep order consistent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem is that my divs are being ordered so that the first column collapses first and is read first on mobiles (intended).

But on word-wrapping at very specific screen dimensions, the divs get out of balance and now look a little funky on their vertical balance with each other.

An image can be found here (red shows divs):

[image]

What I want is to add some space on the text that wasn't word wrapped so that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, Id say the current design works well, as it can fit and change to different screen sizes, the fact that it doesnt line up is understandable as the word is just to long.

However if you wanted to you could set a min-width on the container which represents that box. This means the word wouldnt be wrapped when the screen gets smaller. But it could come with side effects as it will push over the other two divs depending on how the css works.